# Filtering aggregated values in MYSQL database II

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with the following tables `store`, `fruits`,  `vegetables`.

The data is structured like this:

```
Store table 
ID NAME
1, 'red fruit store';
2, 'blue fruit store';
3, 'orange fruit store';

Fruits table
ID STORE_ID PRODUCT_NAME
1, 1, 'orange';
2, 1, 'apple';
3, 1, 'banana';
4, 2, 'apple';
5, 3, 'banana';
6, 3, 'pear';

Vegetables table
ID STORE_ID PRODUCT_NAME
1, 1, 'tomato';
2, 1, 'carrot';
3, 1, 'potato';
4, 2, 'cabbage';
5, 3, 'tomato';
6, 3, 'carrot';
```

If I want to select the store having

- apple and NOT banana
- and tomato or cabbage

How can I do that ?

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name
    FROM store AS s
        INNER JOIN fruits AS f ON s.id = f.store_id
        INNER JOIN vegetables AS v ON s.id = v.store_id
    WHERE (f.product_name LIKE 'apple' AND NOT (f.product_name LIKE 'banana')) AND (v.name LIKE 'tomato' OR v.name LIKE 'cabbage')
    GROUP BY s.id, s.name 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Count and compare or check existence.  But show what you have tried at least -and maybe try to adapt the answers given in your last post.

Comment: expected output please

Comment: @  M.Hemant : I need the ID of the store...

Comment: Don't use LIKE without a pattern, use = **f.product_name='apple'**

Comment: (I'm posting this comment here because for the last 5 mins I can't post a comment under my answer). Because the WHERE clause would limit the rows before you apply grouping. Maybe this limit does not affect the result but maybe it does.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must group by id, name of the store after you join the tables and put all the conditions in the HAVING clause:

```
select s.id, s.name
from store s
inner join fruits f on s.id = f.store_id 
inner join vegetables v on s.id = v.store_id
group by s.id, s.name
having 
  sum(f.product_name = 'apple') > 0
  and
  sum(f.product_name = 'banana') = 0
  and
  sum(v.product_name in ('tomato', 'cabbage')) > 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gM3CLDXbcvPNyDK5trKXaD/1).
Results:

```
| id  | name             |
| --- | ---------------- |
| 2   | blue fruit store |
```

Comment: I need to select store where there is apple and NOT banana

Comment: I have a large database (over 1 mil. rows), if I put a WHERE in the query it is considerably faster:

     `WHERE f.product_name LIKE 'apple' AND f.product_name NOT LIKE 'banana' AND ( v.product_name LIKE 'tomato' OR v.product_name LIKE 'cabbage')` 

Is this OK, or is there a problem if I insert a WHERE clause

Comment: Is there a difference using `sum(f.product_name = 'apple') > 0` or `count('f.product_name = 'apple') > 0` ?

Comment: When you are grouping over all the rows of the table, WHERE and HAVING are 2 different things. WHERE limits the rows and then you apply grouping. HAVING limits the rows after the grouping. In this case WHERE would be wrong. `sum(f.product_name = 'apple') > 0` and `count(f.product_name = 'apple')` are also 2 different things, regardless that there are cases that they return the same value. In this case if you try it all `count(f.product_name = 'orange')` and 
`count(f.product_name = 'apple')` and `count(f.product_name = 'banana')` return the same value.

Comment: With using `WHERE` I mean using it with `HAVING`, using both of them so the query is faster. Without the `WHERE` the query only using `HAVING` takes 20 sec. Using 'WHERE` and `HAVING` it takes only 5 sec.

Comment: Do you get correct results if you use WHERE? Even if you do I'm not sure if they are really correct or they seem correct due to the data you have.

Comment: I'm not trying to argue, I'm just trying to understand: I can make a query that is valid looking like this: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition GROUP BY table.id, table.name HAVING some condition` so why would this return wrong result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS and NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name
    FROM store AS s
        INNER JOIN fruits AS f ON s.id = f.store_id 
        INNER JOIN vegetables AS v ON s.id = v.store_id
    WHERE exists (select * from fruits x where s.id = x.store_id and x.product_name ='apple')
          and not exists (select * from fruits y where s.id = y.store_id and y.product_name ='banana')
          and exists (select * from vegetables x where s.id = z.store_id and (z.name ='tomato' or z.name ='cabbage'))
```